# Определение статуса Caps Lock в приложении

Tags: java, javafx, события

**Всем доброго времени суток!**
В приложении необходимо указывать пользователю нажат ли Caps Lock на клавиатуре.
Участок кода ниже показывает правильное значение при запуске:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Но если нажимать Caps Lock во время работы приложения то он выводит тот статус что был при запуске.
Мне необходимо знать статус Caps Lock во время выполнения приложения.

Приложение написано с GUI на JavaFX.

*P.S. Заранее благодарен за помощь.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `Application.start` получаем состояние `Caps Lock` и пишем в поле статуса. Далее в том же `Application.start` ставим обработчик события отпускания кнопки клавиатуры:

```
Scene scene = ...;
scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.CAPS) {
        boolean isCapsLockOn = 
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(
                java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
        // Обновляем поле статуса.
    }
});
```

Как верно заметил @AndrewBystrov, если сцена неактивна, то обработчик не сработает и наш статус может оказаться невалидным. Поэтому "повесим" обработчик также и на событие получения фокуса:

```
Stage stage = ...;
stage.focusedProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
        if (newValue && !oldValue) { 
            boolean isCapsLockOn = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(
                                       java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); 
            // Обновляем поле статуса.
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить изначальный статус, а потом обрабатывать в keyListener